# How to delete all the resulting rows from a SQL server select A.* query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to delete all the results from a query I made (which detects duplicates based on 3 identical columns, and then selects the one with the lowest row ID).

I have found some similar questions on SO, but I cannot get it to work in combination with putting my query results into A.*

My current query does what I want it to (it may not be fully optimized, but it takes 2 seconds which is fine for now), I just need to delete everything it returns.

I tried adding something along the lines of `DELETE FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]` to the beginning of the query, but I can't quite seem to get it right. I am not sure whether I it's a syntax or logic issue.

```
/* returns the list I want, with a single row of 
all my duplicates based on 3 properties. 
Now I want to delete these rows */

begin tran

SELECT A.*
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] A
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT Prop1,
           Prop2,
           [prop 3]
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
   GROUP BY Prop1,
            [prop 3],
            Prop2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B 
ON A.Prop1= B.Prop1
AND A.Prop2 = B.Prop2
AND A.[prop 3] = B.[prop 3]
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MIN(id)
     FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
     GROUP BY Prop1,
              [prop 3],
              Prop2)
ORDER BY [prop 3]
ROLLBACK
```

Edit:

Based on 3BK's answer, I simple had to change `SELECT` to `DELETE`, and change `A.*` to `A`

The working result:

```
begin tran

DELETE A
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] A
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT Prop1,
           Prop2,
           [prop 3]
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
   GROUP BY Prop1,
            [prop 3],
            Prop2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B 
ON A.Prop1= B.Prop1
AND A.Prop2 = B.Prop2
AND A.[prop 3] = B.[prop 3]
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MIN(id)
     FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
     GROUP BY Prop1,
              [prop 3],
              Prop2)
ORDER BY [prop 3]
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `SELECT A.*`, then you can also `DELETE A`.  The conditions of the `JOIN` you have created should simply ensure that what is being deleted is only those rows that would have been returned from the `SELECT`.

I'm assuming that your `ROLLBACK` is because you're testing, so you simply copy your `SELECT` statement to be after the `DELETE` and check to see what's returned.

Good luck.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I updated the answer with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use cte:

I've try cte already by deleting records

```
;with del_cte as 
(

SELECT A.*
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] A
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT Prop1,
           Prop2,
           [prop 3]
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
   GROUP BY Prop1,
            [prop 3],
            Prop2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B 
ON A.Prop1= B.Prop1
AND A.Prop2 = B.Prop2
AND A.[prop 3] = B.[prop 3]
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MIN(id)
     FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
     GROUP BY Prop1,
              [prop 3],
              Prop2)
ORDER BY [prop 3]
)

delete from del_cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried

```
Delete form tablename where id in ( your query )
```

Hope it helps:-

```
Delete [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
where id in
(
SELECT id
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] A
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT Prop1,
           Prop2,
           [prop 3]
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
   GROUP BY Prop1,
            [prop 3],
            Prop2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B 
ON A.Prop1= B.Prop1
AND A.Prop2 = B.Prop2
AND A.[prop 3] = B.[prop 3]
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MIN(id)
     FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
     GROUP BY Prop1,
              [prop 3],
              Prop2)
)
```